# Is it possible to get a completely new instance of Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I accidentally deleted some configuration files, and now the terminal no longer displays `my_name@project_name:~$`, but `my_name@some_instance:~$`. Is there a way to get a completely new instance for Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your Cloud Shell home directory into clean state as follows:

- Run `ls -a $HOME` and make sure you don't have any files you care about.
- Run `sudo rm -rf $HOME` to delete the home directory.
- In Cloud Shell menu, click the gear icon, then click "Restart Cloud Shell".  Click "Restart Cloud Shell" in the dialog to confirm the action.
- Wait until the new VM is provisioned.  This may take a couple minutes.  Since your home directory does not exist, the directory and the default configuration files will be recreated.
- You should be good now.